# Is there a way to make a SELECT in BigQuery query conditionally only if a table exists?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an app that has to query hundreds of  BigQuery tables (in a Dataflow job) , some of which may not exist (there are tables named by day for events which occur on each day, and some days some tables may not have been created).

Is there a way to write a BQ SQL query such that it makes a SELECT against some_table *if* and only if the named table exists, and returns no rows otherwise?

Someone had posted a query which returns if a table exists

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(1) AS table_count
FROM `my-project:blah.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
WHERE table_id = 'some-table-name-2017-04-02'
```

But we are trying to do a job in Dataflow, and its difficult to make these queries first outside of the dataflow control structure.

Is there a way to combine something like the query above with a SELECT against that table 'some-table-name-2017-04-02', in a single SQL statement such that if the table does not exist, we just get no rows back, rather than an error?

The problem is that the BigQuery SQL parser will not even compile a query if it references a table name that does not exist, even if no query is done to that table.

Comment: Instead of having hundreds of tables would it work for you if you had just one table per day with a schema where you have data separated by date, events and everything else you need?  This way you would guarantee to have tables everyday and not have a problem if some query returns no data for a given date and event.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check budd

```
 if not exists
(select * from sysobjects where name="my table")
begin
 execute "create table mytable(x int)"
 end
```